# How to get list Tables name In asp .net from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want a list of all my tables from database.
i ve this code in SQL, but i dont know how to use it in c#.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

I can acess to my tables from _context.(TBL...)

Comment: are you already making connections to the database with a connection string from your c# code? are you already able to send queries to the database and handle the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    List<string> results = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM sys.tables").ToList();
}
```